# Girl who keeps reincarnating after being betrayed, first life love, hero, becomes a demon king

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

It's about a girl who already reincarnated like 3-4 times and always as the hero's love but all the heroes end up betraying her (go with the princess, priestess etc.) And she always ends at having a bad life. Than when she reincarnates again she is again the hero's love but doesn't want to get hurt again so after the hero leaves to kill the demon king she moves to the city but this time the hero doesn't betray her and then they realise that the demon king who they were killing was just a clone. The demon king was her first life love and a hero but after the people beat his love he became demon king.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for *Kondo koso Shiawase ni Narimasu!*

> Most distinctly, Louisa remembers three of her former lives. In each of them, she was the childhood friend and lover of the hero, the hero promised to return for her, and the Demon Lord was defeated—but the hero abandoned her.
>
> While Louisa waves off her lover Graham as he ventures off to defeat the Demon Lord, she promises to wait for him. However, she knows more than anything else that he won't return. Not wanting to waste away her youth like in her previous lives, she seeks work in the city where she hopes to meet new friends and perhaps find new love.
>
> But not everything is as it seems. Louisa's dreams are plagued by a mysterious girl and a dark-haired man who calls for "Jun." Her continued connection to the hero may not be pure coincidence, and the truth to all of this lies buried deep in her memories of the past.